# How to convert a Unicode code point to characters in C++ using ICU?

Tags: c++, unicode, icu

Somehow I couldn't find the answer in Google. Probably I'm using the wrong terminology when I'm searching. I'm trying to perform a simple task, convert a number that represents a character to the characters itself like in this table: http://unicode-table.com/en/#0460

For example, if my number is 47 (which is '\'), I can just put 47 in a `char` and print it using `cout` and I will see in the console a backslash (there is no problem for numbers lower than 256).

But if my number is 1120, the character should be 'Ѡ' (omega in Latin). I assume it is represented by several characters (which `cout` would know to convert to 'Ѡ' when it prints to the screen).

How do I get these "several characters" that represent 'Ѡ'?

I have a library called ICU, and I'm using UTF-8.

Comment: Some information here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16208079/how-to-work-with-utf-8-in-c-conversion-from-other-encodings-to-utf-8

Comment: There's no characters that you can touch with your fingers, or nail to a wall, or store in a computer. Characters are abstract mathematical entities, just like numbers. You can think of a character, but not actually have it in a tangible form. All you can have is a *representation* of a character. The "unicode number" you already have is a perfectly good representation of a character. If you need some other representation, you need to know which one.

Comment: BTW: Some characters are number (unicode codepoint) sequences, not all of those always though. To your question: Just do a recode from UTF-32 to UTF-8. The [tag:utf-8] tag wiki has a link to the official algorithm.

Comment: (Continued) UTF-8 is another good representation, if you need that, you can use u_strFromUTF32 and u_strToUTF8 to convert from "unicode numbers" (that's UTF32) to ICU strings and from ICU strings to UTF8, respectively. (ICU uses UTF16 internally, so no direct conversion from UTF32 to UTF8).

Comment: n.m thanks for that last comment, i will try it :)

Comment: “which `cout` would know to convert to 'Ѡ'” – actually `cout` doesn’t know anything and does not convert. It just passes whatever bytes it gets through to the system.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you call *Unicode number* is typically called a *code point*. If you want to work with C++ and Unicode strings, ICU offers a *icu::UnicodeString* class. You can [find the documentation here](http://www.icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classicu_1_1UnicodeString.html).

To create a *UnicodeString* holding a single character, you can use the [constructor that takes a code point in a *UChar32*](http://www.icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classicu_1_1UnicodeString.html#a8cba7d9b1942864c841751d62ebf70af):

```
icu::UnicodeString::UnicodeString(UChar32 ch)
```

Then you can call the [*toUTF8String*](http://www.icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classicu_1_1UnicodeString.html#a05777d826515a20a0b2bb8f4108f9348) method to convert the string to UTF-8.

Example program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <unicode/unistr.h>

int main() {
    icu::UnicodeString uni_str((UChar32)1120);
    std::string str;
    uni_str.toUTF8String(str);
    std::cout << str << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

On a Linux system like Debian, you can compile this program with:

```
g++ so.cc -o so -licuuc
```

If your terminal supports UTF-8, this will print an omega character.

Comment: Good example, just a couple of comments - you might use #include <unicode/unistr.h> as that is the typical convention. Also, if you #include <unicode/ustream.h>  you can just do `std::cout << uni_str << std::endl`

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to do it using only standard components. The following example treats the Unicode code point as a `std::u32string` and returns it as a `std::string`.

Creating a `std::u32string` with a Unicode code point is simple:

Method 1: using brace init (calling `initializer_list ctor)

```cpp
std::u32string u1{codePointNumber};
// For example:
std::u32string u1{305}; // 305 is 'ı'
```

Method 2: using operator +=

```cpp
std::u32string u2{}; // Empty string
// For example:
u2 += 305;
```

To convert `std::u32string` to a `std::string`, you can use `std::wstring_convert` from the `<locale>` header:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#include <codecvt>
#include <string>
#include <locale>

std::string U32ToStr(const std::u32string& str)
{
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<char32_t>, char32_t> conv;
    return conv.to_bytes(str);
}

int main()
{
    std::u32string u1{305};
    std::cout << U32ToStr(u1) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

[example 1 from goldbold](https://godbolt.org/z/xfjEPre8s)

Note that `std::wstring_convert` is deprecated (yet not removed) in C++17 and later, so you may want to use an alternative method if you are using a newer version of C++.