# printf escaped unicode character from integer

Tags: c++, unicode, printf

I'm doing a rewrite of this question.

I want to create a string with a unicode escaped character such as `"\u03B1"` using an integer constant.  For example, this string is the greek letter alpha.

```
const char *alpha = "\u03B1"
```

I want to construct the same string using a call to printf using the integer value `0x03B1`.  For this example it can be done like this but I'm not sure to get those two numbers from `0x03B1`.

```
printf("%c%c", 206, 177);
```

This link explains what to do but I'm not sure how to do it.
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/utf8.htm

> For characters equal to or below 2047 (hex 0x07FF), the UTF-8
>   representation is spread across two bytes. The first byte will have
>   the two high bits set and the third bit clear (i.e. 0xC2 to 0xDF). The
>   second byte will have the top bit set and the second bit clear (i.e.
>   0x80 to 0xBF).

*NOTE: I do not want to create the string `"\\u03B1"` with a backslash.  This is different than `"\u03B1"` which is an escaped unicode character.*

Comment: C or C++, pick one because answers will vary wildly.

Comment: `printf("\\u%04x", 1234);`

Comment: Clarify whether you want to end up with the string `'\', 'u', '1', '2', '3', '4', '\0'`, or whether you are trying to build a single character of code point U+1234

Comment: Also, does your console directly support wide Unicode charcaters, or do you need to output UTF8?

Comment: I removed the c++ tag.  @rslemos, close but I want the string to be "\u1234" not "\\u1234".

Comment: If you want a backslash, you need to escape it, so type two of them. does `printf("\\u%04x", 0x1234)` do what you want?

Comment: @BerryBlue go on and try it.

Comment: After investigating further, it looks like the `\u` syntax is C99. Unfortunately, I haven't found a way to do what you're asking. I don't know of a good C99 reference, off the top of my head. Sorry. What you are describing won't work at all in C89.

Comment: Maybe you could add tags for `unicode` and `c99` to get more people who might be able to answer your question. Or maybe change `c` to `c++`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

The first byte contains the 5 upper bits `0x7c0 is 11111000000` and the second byte contains the lower 5 bits `0x3f is 00000111111` of the unicode value.

The first byte uses the mask `0xc0 is 11000000` to set the two high bits and the second byte uses `0x80 is 10000000` to set the first high bit.

```
int alpha = 0x03B1; // 945
char byte1 = 0xc0 | ((alpha & 0x7c0) >> 6); // 206
char byte2 = 0x80 | (alpha & 0x3f); // 177
printf("%c%c", byte1, byte2);
```

Comment: Did you account for the BOM?

Answer (score 3):

It appears that even the most recent C and C++ standards are a bit disappointing in their handling of Unicode.

For those who are confused about the example in the question, like I was:

```
const char *alpha = "\u03B1"
```

In C99, this will store a pointer to the string `"α"` (U+03B1) in `alpha`. In C89, this is invalid syntax.

I could not find a way to use the `\u` syntax with a variable or integer constant, like what the question was requesting. You may be better off using a library to add better Unicode support to your program. I have not used the [ICU library](http://userguide.icu-project.org/), but it sounds promising.

- [How to convert a Unicode code point to characters in C++ using ICU?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23322438/how-to-convert-a-unicode-code-point-to-characters-in-c-using-icu): possibly an answer to your question
- [Unicode Processing in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55641/unicode-processing-in-c): a related Stack Overflow question

Comment: Sorry, please see my edited question above.  I want to create an escaped unicode character not a string with a backslash.