# C++ Non ASCII letters

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

How do i loop through the letters of a string when it has non ASCII charaters?
This works on Windows!

```
for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++)
{
    std::cout << text[i]
}
```

But on linux if i do:

```
std::string text = "á";
std::cout << text.length() << std::endl;
```

It tells me the string "á" has a length of 2 while on windows it's only 1
But with ASCII letters it works good!

Comment: Read about Unicode and UTF8 UTF16 encoding.

Comment: I assume because a string consists out of the letter and '\0', therefore a length of two.

Comment: Perhaps use `std::wstring`?

Comment: @arc_lupus, `std::string` doesn't count the nul terminator in `length()`.

Comment: [Joel on Software's The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html). On Windows if you switch to a codepage without the character `á` you'll see strange thing happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your windows system's [code page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_code_page), á is a single byte character, i.e. every `char` in the `string` is indeed a character. So you can just loop and print them.

On Linux, á is represented as the multibyte (2 bytes to be exact) utf-8 character 'C3 A1'. This means that in your `string`, the á actually consists of *two* `char`s, and printing those (or handling them in any way) separately yields nonsense. This will never happen with ASCII characters because the utf-8 representation of every ASCII character fits in a single byte.

Unfortunately, utf-8 is not really supported by C++ standard facilities. As long as you only handle the whole `string` and neither access individual `char`s from it nor assume the length of the `string` equals the number of actual characters in the `string`, `std::string` will most likely do fine.

If you need more utf-8 support, look for a good library that implements what you need.

You might also want to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402283/stdwstring-vs-stdstring) for a more detailed discussion on different character sets on different systems and advice regarding `string` vs. `wstring`.

Also have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16208079/how-to-work-with-utf-8-in-c-conversion-from-other-encodings-to-utf-8) for information on how to handle different character encodings portably.

Comment: Windows doesn't always use Windows-1252

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Here it apparently did (or it used another encoding where á is a single byte character, which was the point of the question and answer). But you are right, this is a little bit imprecise. Sadly, I do not know too much about how Windows handles such characters when it doesn't use Windows-1252, if you know how to formulate this better, feel free to edit or answer yourself.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Tried to make it better, is this correct as it stands?

Comment: IMHO "In your Windows system's codepage, á is a single byte character" is more correct

Comment: @celticminstrel That does indeed seem to provide at least some facilities. If it does everything you need, you can certainly use it. But as you can see in the table [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt), it has its limitations.

Answer (score 1):

Try using std::wstring. The encoding used isn't supported by the standard as far as I know, so I wouldn't save these contents to a file without a library that handles a specific format. of some sort. It supports multi-byte characters so you can use letters and symbols not supported by ASCII.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::wstring text = L"áéíóú";

    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++)
        std::wcout << text[i];

    std::wcout << text.length() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Questionable advice for Linux systems since utf-8 is based on a series of single byte characters that get interpreted in a special way. Unfortunately, `wchar_t` is still a fixed width character type, which still does not match the variable length encoding utf-8 uses, at least not better than `char` (and thus `std::string`) does. You might want to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402283/stdwstring-vs-stdstring).

Comment: Thanks! I was recommending as it is a solution that would work on multiple platforms in a consistent manner, however. If you are solely using  Linux I definitely would recommend `std::string`.

Comment: Is std::u16string worth using? Is it portable?

Comment: @kovacsmarcell I would not fiddle with utf16 if I was you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16208079/how-to-work-with-utf-8-in-c-conversion-from-other-encodings-to-utf-8 http://utf8everywhere.org/

Comment: It's still a variable length encoding, as well.

Comment: is std::wstring portable? (I don't want to save it to a file)