# utf8mb4 encode/decode in c++

Tags: c++, character-encoding, utf8mb4

A third-part server echoes string to my client program, the string contains both utf8 data and unicode emoji (listed [here](http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode)). for example:

[image: eg]

I googled some time and found this is called **utf8mb4** encoding, which is used in SQL application.

I find some article about utf8mb4 in mysql/python/ruby/etc... but no c++.
Is there any c++ library can do encoding/decoding utf8mb4?

Comment: utf8 by definition can't be 5 bytes (see for example [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-unicode-utf8.html) that references various standards). So the right part of the image is wrong. MySQL calls [utf8mb4 what is in truth utf8](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html), so any library that supports utf8 will give you utf8mb4. What MySQL calls utf8 is up-to-3-bytes utf8 (see the same page)

Comment: Sorry I've updated the image, the right part is two three-byte utf8 data.

Comment: In C++11 they added directly in the C++ libraries some standard way to do it: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MySQL calls utf8mb4 what is in truth utf8](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html):

> The character set named utf8 uses a maximum of three bytes per character and contains only BMP characters. As of MySQL 5.5.3, the utf8mb4 character set uses a maximum of four bytes per character supports supplemental characters:

so any library that supports utf8 will give you utf8mb4. In this question it was asked what solutions are there in C++ for converting to/from utf8: [How to work with UTF-8 in C++, Conversion from other Encodings to UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16208079/613130) . The three solutions given are [ICU (International Components for Unicode)](http://site.icu-project.org/), [Boost.Locale](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0_b1/libs/locale/doc/html/index.html) and C++11.

Comment: I tried the c++ 11 version, here's my code: `http://pastebin.com/gkCUaS5U`, but after convering to std::wstring, the emoji was lost, the wstring only contains three 'a'.

Comment: @aj3423 Strange: https://ideone.com/5iAhzF prints 6. What compiler are you using?

Comment: Sorry my mistake ,the length is 6,  "\x61\x00\x61\x00\x61\x00". it only contains the three 'a', the rest are gone.

Comment: @aj3423 You are confusing `char` with `wchar_t`. `sizeof(wchar_t)` is 2 (Visual C++) or 4 bytes long (GCC). So it is 6x wchar_t. See the revised example: https://ideone.com/KAACJt

Comment: @aj3423 Technically in C++11 to solve the problem that `wchar_t` wasn't uniquely defined (lets say that in Visual C++ it is UTF-16, while in GCC it is UTF-32), they created a whole group of new containers for UTF-16 and UTF-32, `char16_t`, `char32_t`, `u16string`, `u32string`, plus some new literals (as seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796157/unicode-encoding-for-string-literals-in-c11)

Comment: A fourth solution is [Ogonek](https://github.com/rmartinho/ogonek). Still not mature though. But by far (!!!) the best API of any of the alternatives.

Comment: @aj3423 Ok... It is a cesspit... Two (three) problems: Visual C++ has a 2 bytes `wchar_t` that can't contain all the unicode characters. Ideone uses GCC that has `wchar_t` of 4 bytes. Use this line: `std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t> > cvt_utf8;`. This will convert from utf8 to utf16, while the other line I had given you was converting to UCS2/UCS4. Second problem: you can't `wcout << L"ws: " << ws << endl`, because the `wcout`  breaks and stops working (I don't know why). The `for` cycle works correctly. https://ideone.com/KAACJt Note that now the length is 7xUTF-16 points

Comment: `\x61\x00` is not `char` for `a`.  Emoji need 4 bytes of utf8 or 2 words of utf16 or 1 word of utf32.  One wchar_t (if it is only 16 bits) cannot hold an Emoji.