# Is there C# `Encoding.UTF8.GetString` equivalent in C++?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-c++

Is there C# `Encoding.UTF8.GetString` equivalent in C++ ? Or another fast way parse byte array containing the sequence of bytes and decode to string.

Comment: Check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16208079/how-to-work-with-utf-8-in-c-conversion-from-other-encodings-to-utf-8

Comment: Is good solution but I can't parse byte array by `index` such as `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byte[], index int, count int);`.

Comment: The answer depends a lot on what you mean by "string". The closest to C#'s `String` is probably `std::wstring`, in which case you may be looking for `std::wstring_convert<codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>>().from_bytes(your_utf8_byte_ptr)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
auto *wstrBytes = new wchar_t[size];
memcpy_s(wstrBytes , size, rawBytes, size);
std::wstring unicodeStr(wstrBytes , size);
delete [] wstrBytes;
```